# How do I formally show the radius of convergence of the Taylor series of $f(x)=x^6 - x^4 + 2$ at $a=-2$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

This is an exercise in Stewart's *Calculus* (Exercise 19, Section 11.10 Taylor and Maclaurin Series):

> Find the Taylor series for $f(x)$ centered at the given value of a. [Assume that f has a power series expansion. Do not show that $R_n(x) \to 0.$ Also find the associated radius of convergence.
>
> Here $f(x)=x^6 - x^4 + 2$ and $a=-2$.

---

I'm having trouble finding a general formula of this Taylor series and therefore, also having problems finding the radius of convergence since I can't perform the ratio test.

Here is what I know:
\begin{align}
f'(x) = 6x^5 - 4x^3,\quad     &f''(x) = 30x^4 - 12x^2,\\
f'''(x) = 120x^3 - 24x,\quad  &f^{(4)}(x) = 360x^2 - 24,\\
f^{(5)}(x) = 720x,\quad         &f^{(6)}(x) = 720.
\end{align}

And at $a=-2$,
\begin{align}
f(-2) = 50,\quad     &f'(-2) = -160,\\
f''(-2) = 432,\quad  &f'''(-2) = -912,\\
f^{(4)}(-2) = 1416,\quad         &f^{(5)}(-2) = -1440,\\
f^{(6)}(-2) = 720.\quad    &
\end{align}

I'm having trouble finding the general formula for each term. Without it, how am I supposed to find the radius of convergence?

---

**Added:**
So the general term I have for the n-th derivative of $f$ is:

$$f^{(n)}(x) = \frac{6!x^{6-n}}{(6-n)!}$$

So far the general term I have for the Taylor Series is:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{6! 2^{6-n}}{(6-n)!n!}(x+2)^n$$

I can see why the radius of convergence is $\infty$: because for any $x$the series converges.

But how do I show this formally? Can I use the ratio test?

Answer (score 2):

Your general form of the derivative is wrong. It is valid only up to $n=6$. After that it is $0$. So your sum consist only of terms up to $(x+2)^6$. You therefore have a finite sum, not an infinite number of terms, neither of which diverges.

Comment: Mind writing it out? The general term? I'm a bit lost

Comment: The general term for $n>6$ is $f^{(n)}=0$. You have the first six terms already calculated. Just calculate the next derivative. The derivative of a constant is ... I just realized that you general formula does not even apply to the first 4 terms, just for 5 and 6.

Answer (score 1):

Sticking to the definition helps. Recall that the Taylor series of $f$ centered at a given value of $a$ is by definition

$$
f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n
=f(a)+\frac{f'(a)}{1!}(x-a)+\frac{f''(a)}{2!}(x-a)^2+\frac{f'''(a)}{3!}(x-a)^2+\cdots\tag{1}
$$

Now, given the expression of $f$, namely, $f(x)=x^6-x^4+2$, and value of $a=-2$, all you need to do is finding ${f^{(n)}(-2)}$ for each $n=0,1,2,\cdots$. You have already found the values of $f^{(n)}(-2)$ for $n=0,1,\cdots,6$, which gives you the first seven terms in the Taylor series:
$$
f(-2)+\frac{f'(-2)}{1!}(x+2)+\frac{f''(-2)}{2!}(x+2)^2+\cdots+\frac{f^{(6)}(-2)}{3!}(x+2)^2.\tag{2}
$$
On the other hand, $f^{(n)}(a)=0$ for any integer $n>6$. Hence, by (1), the Taylor series for $f$ at $a=-2$ is
$$
f(-2)+\frac{f'(-2)}{1!}(x+2)+\frac{f''(-2)}{2!}(x+2)^2+\cdots+\frac{f^{(6)}(-2)}{3!}(x+2)^2+0+0+0+\cdots\tag{3}
$$
which is a finite sum, and of course it is convergent for every $x$.

---

Note that (3) can be written formally as a power series, which seems to be what you were looking for, as follows:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n(x+2)^n\quad\textrm{where }
c_0=f(-2),\ c_1=\frac{f'(-2)}{1!},\cdots, c_6=\frac{f^{(6)}(-2)}{6!},\ c_7=c_8=\cdots =0.\tag{4}
$$
You do *not* need Root Test or Ratio Test to get the radius of convergence but only need to look at the **definition** of the "radius of convergence". See the definition below Theorem 4 of Section 11.8 in Stewart's Calculus (your textbook), in particular case (ii):

> [image]

Comment: @Jwan622: Do I answer your question? Are you still confused?

Answer (score 0):

The Taylor series around $a$ is simply given by $$\begin{align}f(a+x)&=(a+x)^6-(a+x)^4+2\\&=(a^6-a^4+2)+(6a^5-4a^3)x+(15a^4-6a^2)x^2+(20a^3-4a)x^3+(15a^2-1)x^4+6ax^5+x^6\end{align}$$
or
$$f(x)= (a^6-a^4+2)+(6a^5-4a^3)(x-2)+(15a^4-6a^2)(x-a)^2+(20a^3-4a)(x-a)^3+(15a^2-1)(x-a)^4+6a(x-a)^5+(x-a)^6$$

and, as almost all coefficients are $=0$, converges for all $x$.